# Kafka streams - First example WordCount doesn't work (Count values are wrong)

Tags: spring-boot, apache-kafka, apache-kafka-streams

I'm using KafkaStreams and Confluent and I'm trying to develop a 'wordcount' stream.

Basically, the idea is to read from a topic (wordcount-input), count the number of words, and write to another topic (wordcount-output) the number of words.

The implementation seems simple, but when looking at the output topic in Confluent, instead of showing the value, I get the following output.

[Input topic](https://i.stack.imgur.com/TCVee.png)

[Output topic](https://i.stack.imgur.com/uhaWA.png)

Below, I attach the code of the typology developed.

```
StreamsBuilder builder = new StreamsBuilder();

// reading from input topic
KStream<String, String> textLines = builder.stream("wordcount-input", Consumed.with(Serdes.String(), Serdes.String()));

KStream<String, Long> wordsCount = textLines
   .mapValues((ValueMapper<? super String, ? extends String>) String::toLowerCase)
   .flatMapValues(value -> Arrays.asList(value.split(" "))).selectKey((ignoredKey, word) -> word)
   .groupByKey()
   .count()
   .toStream();
  
// writing to output topic
wordsCount.to("wordcount-output", Produced.with(Serdes.String(), Serdes.Long()));
```

As a test, I'm extracting the information through the console, and works fine, so the failure is when sending the output topic.

```
wordsCount.foreach((k,v) -> System.out.println(k + "--" + v));
```

**Do you know what is happening?**

*Annexed*

```
// configuration properties
properties.put(StreamsConfig.APPLICATION_ID_CONFIG, "kafka-streams-test-app");
properties.put(StreamsConfig.BOOTSTRAP_SERVERS_CONFIG, "localhost:9092");
properties.put(StreamsConfig.DEFAULT_KEY_SERDE_CLASS_CONFIG, Serdes.String().getClass());
properties.put(StreamsConfig.DEFAULT_VALUE_SERDE_CLASS_CONFIG, Serdes.String().getClass());
properties.put(ConsumerConfig.AUTO_OFFSET_RESET_CONFIG, "earliest");
```

Answer (score 0):

I found no problems with your topology in your fragment of code. (It would be useful to see the complete code).
The problem can be in the dashboard, You should check by creating a Kafka consumer,  Using a StringDeserializer for the Key and LongDeserializer for the value, and subscribe to your output topic. Don't forget to use the  AUTO_OFFSET_RESET_CONFIG earliest to see your existing messages.